# Not sending data to Parse.com after being compiled with PhoneGap

Tags: android, mobile, coffeescript, cordova, parse-platform

When I test out my app on my browser, it sends data to the Parse.com data browser fine.

But when I compile it using "PhoneGap Build" and run it (either from an android emulator or from an android device), it doesn't send the data to the Parse.com server, and results in an error message.

So, I feel that the problem may be related to PhoneGap and not Parse...?

```
add: (addeditem) ->
    if @mode is "online" #upload to server
        Item = Parse.Object.extend("Item");
        item = new Item();
        console.log "parse item", item
        item.save
            data: addeditem
        ,
        success: (gameTurnAgain) ->
            # The save was successful.
            alert "success"

        error: (gameTurnAgain, error) ->
            # The save failed.  Error is an instance of Parse.Error.
            alert error.code
            alert error.message
            console.error(error)
```

When I try to alert "error.code" and "error.message", they come out as "-1" (which means OTHER_CAUSE), and "undefined" respectively.

The entire application is available at https://github.com/anshula/everyday.
The PhoneGap build is available at https://build.phonegap.com/apps/453542/share.

I've tried using the PhoneGap Debug to figure out the problem, but because the error message is so vague, I'm really confused...thank you so much to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually - nevermind! I received help from community.phonegap.com.  The problem was in my config.xml: I had to change

> ```
> <access origin="127.0.0.1*"/>
> ```

to

> ```
> <access origin="*"/>
> ```

so I could let my app access external resources.